# django book for real world web applications

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i need to know, is there any book for django that focus on developing real world web applications ?
I got my basics cleared. now i want to develop a fully featured e-commerce or social networking website. is there any book out there ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Free Programming Books](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#django) give you some option.

But the Django documentation is really good, with a lot a examples and translate in many languages. So I thing you dont really need a book to learn Django.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am a big fan of the [Real Python course](https://realpython.com) (part 3). It's not free, but the content is really thorough. It also covers integrating a frontend framework which communicates with a django REST api.